# Arraylist replace each element with first occurance of some string

Tags: java

I have an arraylist like below

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

 list.add("P Pro Rata(Average Cost w/Tax Lots)");
            list.add("A apple is good");
            list.add("B ball is nice");
            list.add("C cat is not there");
```

I want the first space of each element in the array list should be replaced with : operator(only first space and for each element)

so output should be

```
A:apple is good
B:ball is nice
C:cat is not there
```

I have a solution which iterates and creates new element and add it to new list and using that new list

can any one come up with best solution ?

Comment: You should post the code for the solution you already have first. How can we tell another solution is better without knowing yours?

Comment: A `String` object is immutable, so unless you calculate each one of the final strings **before** adding it to the `ArrayList`, any solution would probably be equivalent in efficiency to the one that you describe (although you **should** add it to your question if you want to be sure of that).

Comment: @Axel : i have mentioned my solution in words..sorry if you have not understood..

Comment: @KaribasappaGC No, it's ok. But I'm sure that was the reason for the downvotes (I didn't)...

Comment: @Axel : thats okie Axel, sometime people dont read properly and down vote simply..we cant do anything for that...thanks for your words

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
        list.set(i,list.get(i).replaceFirst(" ", ":"));
    }
```

Comment: is there any way we can reduce the creation of new string each time we do list.get(i).replaceFirst(" ", ":") ?

Comment: You can use StringBuilder instead of String. and modify the object instead of setting a newer one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf` to find the first occurance of a space in the strings as such:

```
for (String s : list) {
    int index = s.indexOf(" ");
    String prefix = s.substring(0, index);
    String suffix = s.substring(index+1);
    System.out.println(prefix + ":" + suffix);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use for each to iterate array list and replaceFirst will help you replace first char

```
 int i=0;
 for (String s : list){        
    list.set(i,s.replaceFirst(" ", ":"));
    i++;
 }
```